# Xamarin iOS Image Tint Color

Tags: ios, image, xamarin, colors, tint

I want to use an template image which is black and use the tintColor of this image to set the color and to have only one image.

Then I put template image in asset
And I try to change the color by :

```
object.TintColor = UIColor.Blue;
```

But it doesn't work, it still black

Can someone help me please ?

Thanks

Comment: Are you updating it on the UIThread?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You must set the image rendering mode to `AlwaysTemplate` in order to have the TintColor affect your UIImage, otherwise it will display image as is.
It helps control the color of Image to any color you wish to set, with having a single image in Resources or xcassets.

Following Code should Help you.

```
imgViewObject.Image = imgViewObject.Image.ImageWithRenderingMode(UIImageRenderingMode.AlwaysTemplate);
imgViewObject.TintColor = UIColor.Blue;
```

We can also set Rendering Mode from xcassets as shown in following image:

[image: xcassets Render As]

For more details about [Working with Template Images](https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/ios/application_fundamentals/working_with_images/displaying-an-image/#Working_with_Template_Images)

Comment: Oh my god, it works ! But why I need to put ImageWithRenderingMode in code while I put it in assets ?

Comment: I needed to add a tint color to my tiled resizable image and this did the trick

Comment: Can this be set in AppDelegate.cs for system wide iOS usage?